# What's the maximum number of nodes on a path?

Tags: c++, graph, tree

I'm having the following problem:

There are a lot of nodes and several of them are already connected, but not all. We have to add connections such that each node is connected with any other(not neccessary directly). We do not want to change any of the existing connections.
The nodes have to be connected with the least amount of lines (the current connections already follow this rule). Also a path from one node to another must pass through the least amount of other nodes. We want to know the maximum number of nodes on any path, when everything is connected in an optimal way.

**Input:**
The following data is given by user input:
**•** You get two integers: the number 1 ≤ *p* ≤ 1.000.000 of nodes and the
number 0 ≤ *l* ≤ *p* − 1 of existing connections.
**•** Then *l* lines with each two integers *a* and *b* between 0 and *p* − 1 (inclusive), denoting the endpoints of a connection.

**Output:**
The output should be an integer that represents the maximum number of nodes on any path.(so without the beginning and endpoints)

So for example when we have as input *p* = 6, *l* = 4 and the connections 2-0, 1-0, 5-3 and 4-3 the output should be 2.

I already wrote a program in c++ that does the following:

```
int main(){

    int p, l;

    cin >> p >> l;

    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++){

        int a, b;

        cin >> a >> b;

        // store the connection a,b somehow

    }

    // solve the problem

    cout << answer << endl;

}
```

I thought of storing the connections in an p - 1 times p - 1 array, with a 1 if the line exists and 0 otherwise. Furtermore I need something to decide how to make connections in an optimal way and compute the maximum amount of nodes on each path. I'm only allowed to use the standard library of C++.

Could someone please help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "The nodes have to be connected with the least amount of lines (the current connections already follow this rule). Also a path from one node to another must pass through the least amount of other nodes." This seems a contradiction to me. To satisfy the second one you'd need a fully connected graph, that is, a direct line from each node to each other node, with no intermediate ones. But this would maximize the number of lines.

Comment: It has to become a graph where there is a path from every node to any other node. So there are no cykels. Because a cykel would mean an edge that is not neccessary

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a basic algorithms homework...

Given your *existing* graph, find the maximum path. Unless you have only two nodes, this will be your answer.

Connect all your new nodes to any node that is not a leaf node of your maximum path.

(Lines that connect nodes are called "edges".)

Let me know if I have misunderstood your problem.

**edit**
Here is a simple graph.
The maximal path is (a,b,c) [which is the same as (c,b,a) -- we'll always order the two leaves so that the smallest comes first].

```
(a)--(b)--(c)
```

I can find it by picking any *leaf* node -- a node with exactly 1 edge -- and finding my way to another leaf node.
The furthest leaf node will be the longest/maximal path *from that node*.

Do it again from the leaf node you just found, and you will have the longest/maximal path for the entire graph.

Let's examine how that works with a new graph:

```
(a)--(b)--(c)--(d)--(e)--(f)
           |
          (s)
```

I'm going to start at node (s). If I find the longest path from it I will find node (f). Node (f) *must be* one of the endpoints on the longest path in the graph. (I'll leave it to you to think about why.)

Now, I start again at node (f). The longest path from (f) leads to (a). I now have the longest path in the graph: (a,b,c,d,e,f).

Here is another graph:

```
(a)--(b)--(c)
      |
     (d)
```

There are a number of longest paths to choose from. (a,b,c), (a,b,d), and (c,b,d). What matters is that they all exist and have the same length.

Now, to which node should I connect a *new* node (e) so that I don't change the longest path? Easy:

```
     (e)
      |
(a)--(b)--(c)
      |
     (d)
```

You can guarantee this by only attaching a new node to nodes that are *not leaf nodes*.

As for your question about how to represent the graph, your idea will work fine, but remember, you have p nodes, not p-1. So, for example, I can represent my 3-node graph as:

```
       from
      a  b  c 
   a  0  1  0
to b  1  0  1
   c  0  1  0
```

Notice the columns: a only leads to one other node. Likewise, c only leads to one other node. 
However, b's column shows that b leads to *two* other nodes (which is more than one).

Hence, a and c are leaves; b is not.

If I add a new node, I will want to connect it only to nodes that have more than one node already:

```
   a  b  c  d            a  b  c  d
a  0  1  0  0         a  0  1  0  0
b  1  0  1  0   -->   b  1  0  1  1
c  0  1  0  0         c  0  1  0  0
d  0  0  0  0         d  0  1  0  0
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it is algorithms homework. But I'm stuck with it for almost 2 days now, and I'm not asking you guys a perfect working code, only hints so I can program it myself.

Comment: The problem is that I don't see how I can make an optimal connected graph, so how to decide if a node is not a leaf. And I also can't see how to determine what the maximum path is in the graph. Is my idea with the p-1 x p-1 array at least correct? thanks in advance